# How do i remove unused css from magento 2 homepage?

Tags: css, performance, optimization, merge-css

I am not getting good performance when i audit my website with chroome lighthouse. I am getting few errors like 
- Remove unused CSS
- Ensure Text Remain Visible during web front load 
- Minimize main threat work

Please anybody help  me fixing these little things.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried defer parsing CSS?

Comment: no. How to do it ?

Comment: did you figure out how to remove unused css? i'm also looking at pagespeed insights and want to removed some unused css like …merged/055fb59….min.css 509 KB

Comment: no. i am still looking for any solution asno one replied with any solution. Merging css is also necessary and magento is using same merged (big css file) on all pages.

Comment: there are few option for css in this module https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/  but i think it is not reducing css page by page.

Comment: Hi All, Anyone found any solution to this problem?

Comment: @AsharRiaz - did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to use for my page.

First, unmerge, unbundling, un-minify js and CSS

Next, turn on Coverage tab in Chrome DevTools 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage/
then check unused CSS and JS

or you can check each file one by one.

then you can remove a file unused, put code to the layout of the page you want to remove.

Ex: I will remove some file in the homepage so I put to cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="js/bundle/bundle0.js"/>
        <remove src="css/bootstrap-magento.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Hope this solution will solve your issue.

Comment: This is not working specifically to remove the JS - do you have any other solutions ?

Comment: if its JS file, you can use my solution above, if its JS from requirejs-config.js, you need find it in require where JS call and remove it
EX: <script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','masonry','jquery/ui','domReady!'],
function($,Masonry) {

I see i don't want masonry, i will remove it.
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','jquery/ui','domReady!'],
function($) {

Done. JS will not call in your page